# Wordpress приватный доступ к чтению электронных журналов

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У нас есть сайт на вордпресс, без подключенной коммерции, но мы предоставляем на сайте услугу подписки на печатный журнал (идет заявка через сайт на нашу почту, а после чего наш менеджер связывается даёт реквизиты для оплаты ) в общем по такому же принципу оплаты через менеджера мы хотим предоставлять доступ к электронным версиям журнала, которые человек оплатил, возмонжо это есть плагин с личным кабинетом, где мы регистрируем вручную пользователя и даем ему доступ вручную к тем ПДФ журналам  котоыре он оплатил, или может еще какая-то схема. ПОдскажите пожалуйста как нам реализовать эту идею?

Comment: Ответ "правильно" не принимается как единственно верный? А если серьезно то в 2020 году, пора бы от ручного труда отказаться, woocomerce умеет из коробки предоставлять доступ к "скачиваемым" товарам(ваш случай), в том числе и временно, в том числе и после оплаты, и в ручном\автоматическом режиме.

Comment: Вы не прочитали сути. Скачав человек может поделиться с другими, а нам нужно, чтобы человек мог лишь читать  без скачивания в личном кабинете по ссылке только тогда когда у него есть логин пароль от личного кабинета или типо того и чтобы поделиться ему придется делать скриншоты

Comment: Огорчу вас, всё что смотрит человек - он уже скачал и может поделится с кем угодно.

Comment: Боюсь я вас огорчу тоже, давно не ноухау системы, когда вы читаете не скачивая ничего =) Это называется защита авторского права

Comment: Покажите мне ту, из которой я не выдеру информацию =) мне такие не известны, ибо камеру напротив экрана - не отменял никто.
Камера + fine reader + часик-другой времени... ну вы поняли да? 
Все на что способны такие системы - выявить от кого именно утекла информация, но не защитить ее =)

Comment: Хватит оффтопить, жду ответа по готовым решениям моих задач.